# dynamic content using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I been searching for many hours trying to make dynamic page that load content. My code is working loading the div but when i want to revert it to original its not working at all.

this the code for html:

```
<html>
<button id="btn_nav_register">
<button id="btn_nav_manage">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="manage">
       original content
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="register" style="display:none;">
     second content
</div>

</html>
```

here's my jquery

```
<script>

$('#btn_nav_register').click(function() {
        $("#manage").hide(400,function() {
            $("#content").html($("#register").html()).show(400);
        });

});

$('#btn_nav_manage').click(function() {

    $("#register").hide(400,function() {
        $("#content").html($("#manage").html()).show(400);
    });

});

</script>
```

note: i want to keep the code close as possible because i really want to keep the transition of loading content.

Comment: Why not putting both of the DIVs (register, manage) in #content and instead of using the html() function, simply use hide and show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must move the "manage" to out of the "content" :)
Also close the button tags too..

```js
    $('#btn_nav_register').click(function() {
            $("#manage").hide(400,function() {
                $("#content").html($("#register").html()).show(400);
            });

    });

    $('#btn_nav_manage').click(function() {

        $("#register").hide(400,function() {
            $("#content").html($("#manage").html()).show(400);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button type="button" id="btn_nav_register"> b1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_nav_manage"> b2</button>
 <div id="content">

 </div>
<div id="manage" style="display:none;">
     original content
</div>
<div id="register" style="display:none;">
     second content
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_nav_manage').trigger('click'); 
        // auto click button when page is ready for to show default content!
        // or also you can add a name for click function and call it in here
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks you for that but if that's the case how can i make the div "manage" at default when i open the page